# Jeditable edit without losing styles during editing?

Tags: jquery, jeditable

Is it possible to keep the styles whilst editing, kind of like a rich text editor? It currently changes to a plaintext editor but it would be nice if you could just press an edit button and it allows you to (truly) edit in-line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible by styling elements via css properties like

```
.editable form,
.editable input {
    margin: inherit;
    padding: inherit;
    font: inherit;
    color: inherit;
    background: inherit;
    border: inherit
}
```

where `editable` class is a selector for Jeditable

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE:** *JEditable* uses `<button />` node instead of `<input type="button" />`, so for styling buttons via *CSS* you need:

```
.editable button
{
  /** style goes here **/
}
```